# Can't connect to official cs:go servers due to packet loss

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I can't connect to the official valve servers anymore. Community servers still work, but when trying to connect to both competitive or casual servers, I get a weird loadscreen without any texts, my packet loss suddenly rises to 99%, and the console gives out the following error over and over:

```
<Server IP>:corrupted packet -<Some number?> at 0
```

Here is a picture of the loadscreen and the console:

[image]
(There are no texts or pictures behind the console. The relevant parts are highlighted in green)

I opened all ports listed [here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8571-GLVN-8711) and even tried reinstalling the game, but nothing seemed to help.

Comment: Did you ever use some mods vor Skins? Did you try to delete the clientregistry.blob?

Comment: Never used any mods or skins. Deleting clentregistry.blob didn't help.

Comment: did you change anything on your computer or did you change your internet connection? for how long aren't you able to connect?

Comment: well i just looked in the steam forum and there're several people who got the same issue. The Problem seems to be there for around 1 month now but only a few guys got this problem. They say, that a simple steam + cs:go restart fix this problem for the next game.
However, next time you got such a situation copy the server ip, start your cmd.exe and use the command "tracert xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" where xxx[...] is the ip adress. This will show you all connections happening between you and the steam server so you can see where the packages will get lost

Comment: Didn't change anything, just stopped working a couple of weeks ago. Unfortunately, restarting cs, steam or my computer didn't work. I tried the tracert thing, here is what I got: http://i.imgur.com/DuHIuXx.png "Zeitüberschreitung" means timeout, but since you have a german TLD in your name, you probably don't need a translation.

Comment: Yes you're right, i dont need an german translation XP however i dont know if valve allows server tracking so i'm not sure if the tracert could be a hint. I'll try the same tracert as soon as i'm home and tell you the result

Comment: well seems like you cant track valve servers, here's my result in the last 20steps http://i.imgur.com/yXgKb9x.jpg did you try to use the console command "rate 128000" that fix it for a few ppl around

Comment: Changing the rate doesn't work. :(

Comment: then i can't give you any help i'm sorry. I would just ask the official steam support, they should know a fix for that. But you should explain them in detail whats happening and what you already tried else it's possible that they'll give you an answer you already found here. It would be great if you comment here what the support told you

Comment: Try verifying the files, and then restart your computer, as well as your router. Sometimes doing both can help, as I've had this issue, as well as others similar, before. Doing what I said before helped me, so maybe it'll help you :D

Comment: This post is now 2 months old, I think we can safely assume OP tried restarting his Computer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but tried all you said to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it! Switched from LAN to WLAN 2 months ago, switched back today and it worked.

Comment: That seems really odd to me that the network interface would be the problem if you were still able to connect to certain servers.

Comment: wLan is a typical reason for this. I mean, you send Data Packages on the same Wavelenght as your Microwave ;)

Comment: Yeah it really is weird, but I checked right before switching and it didn't work, right after it it worked, so that really seems to be the reason. Also tried it on my girlfriends PC (that was still connected via LAN) a couple of weeks ago and it worked. Back then I just presumed that my computer is the problem.